# Writing to one layer of a texture array and reading from another

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I'm currently implementing depth-peeling in an OpenGL 3D engine. I want to store the values in a depth 2D texture array. The algorithm, at its n'th execution, would need to read the n-1 layer, and if the current value is greater (object far away), insert the current value in the n'th layer. However, we are not supposed to be able to read and write in the same texture.

Would it be possible for example to read from it (only n-1'th layer) and to attach the n'th layer as the depth attachement of the current FBO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, we are not supposed to be able to read and write in the same texture.

Says who?

[Textures](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture) store image***s***. Note the plural. There is no prohibition against reading from and writing to the same texture. The prohibition is against [reading from and writing to *the same image*.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Feedback_Loops)

Array textures contain multiple images. Each array layer is its own 2D image (or set of 2D mipmap images). Therefore, it is perfectly legal to read from one array layer and write to another. It's perfectly legal to read from one mipmap in an array layer and write to another mipmap in the same array layer.

What is not legal is reading/writing on the *same* mipmap of the *same* array layer.

This is why OpenGL doesn't give an error if the same texture is attached to the FBO at the same time it is bound to the rendering context for reading. This is legal as long as you ensure that you're not reading from/writing to the same image.

Comment: Would this also be true for mip-map levels (i.e. within one texture, read from one mip map level, write to another)?

Comment: @rsp1984 Based on what was linked mipmap levels are separate images and can be read/written to just fine as long as they do not overlap. Interestingly based on what they link says array layers are not actually separate images, so sampling from the same mipmap level on different layers is actually undefined behavior unless texture views are used, so I am not sure how accurate this answer is (perhaps the wiki is wrong though).